# What is the easiest way to farm Nazar?

Tags: terraria

I need a Nazar. It is the last ingredient for the Ankh Shield I need and it seems difficult to receive.

Is there a good way to get it?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253060/is-there-any-way-to-increase-the-drop-rate-of-items

Answer (score 3):

Since you have all the other ingredients I surmise that you are in hardmode. I am not yet in hardmode, but I have farmed a nazar. Since the enemies in harmode are much, well, harder I would suggest farming it in a new world that is not in hardmode yet. It takes some time to drop, but the easiest enemy that drops it are the Cursed Skulls in the non-hardmode dungeon.

I would suggest creating a new world, defeating Skeletron, and finding a place in the dungeon where Cursed Skulls spawn. With hardmode gear you shouldn't have too much trouble hanging around waiting for a drop. I used the bee armor with imps, and the vilethorn, but there are probably better loadouts if you have hardmode equipment available. It took me several real time hours though, as you have to get a bit lucky. Using a water candle or battle potion will increase the spawn rate, if you feel that you can handle it.

Good luck.

Comment: If order to see how uncommon it is: if you want to have at least a 90% chance of getting the drop, plan to kill 230 Cursed Skulls. A 99% chance needs to kill about 460. So you will definitely need to plan on spending some time on it.

Comment: Just the one he is looking for. I don't have most of the others. The nazar happens to be one of three components that can be obtained before hardmode. The other eight require hardmode. He said it was the last one he needed, therefore he had the other eight.

Comment: from the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ankh) : The Bezoar (from Hornets) and Nazar (from Cursed Skulls) are the only items you can get pre-hardmode.

Comment: For the Ankh Charm yes, but that combines with the obsidian shield to get the Ankh Shield.

Comment: Tip for future readers: expert mode doubles the drop rate of the Nazar, so in addition to all these tips, make sure you make your new world an expert world.

Comment: But be warned: Expert mode enemys do a lot more damage, so be prepared to die a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a very late comment, but on mobile, I am currently using full chlorophyte armour + water candle in hand + water candle nearby + battle potion for farming a Nazar. Oh, and I also used a new world's dungeon so that I didn't get destroyed by hardmode enemies.

I closed myself in a box, with a 2-block thick roof, with a 2x1 gap in the roof. (having a door is optional, just remember to use a block as a barricade)
-Grapple yourself into the 2x1 gap and the chlorophyte leaf (from full set of chlorophyte armour, and make sure the leaf is poking out of the box) will kill the monsters for you.

I've gotten 2 Nazars and 50+ golden keys from being afk. Dark Casters tend to tp into the box, but they'll teleport out later and be killed by the leaf. You can use minions with the leaf, too.

The Nazar is by far the hardest Ankh Charm item I tried to get. Every item I got in a few minutes, but the Nazar took actual farming.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget dual water candles and battle potions to help speed this up.  Beyond those things, personally, I like to farm with less interactive attacks, like traps and summoned minions.  Swinging the trusty ol'Night's edge is more fun for exploring and bosses in my opinion.

It is also worth taking some time to setup a fighting area to your advantages, since some of these drops can take a long time to get.  For example, clean out the elevation changes, create deflection overhangs (Meteor shot in the minishark or megashark is fun!), make sure that the incoming riff raff has to work to get line of sight on you and place healing items like heart lanterns, heart and star statues, and campfires.  Give yourself the advantages, and if you pay attention to the wall types, you can setup the arena in an area for hardmode spawns that you want to fight later, like for the sniper kit or the paladin shield, for example. (Check out the wiki on hardmode dungeon wall types!)

Since you have gotten to hard mode, a full summoner kit with the pygmy group hanging out in the dungeon should be able to get through large numbers of stuff quickly.  (That assumes you got a pygmy staff drop, if you have not gotten the pygmy staff, get your most powerful spawner!)

Comment: "Multiple Candles will not stack with each other - whether there are several placed, a stack of more than one being held, or a player is holding one while in range of a placed one." http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_Candle

Comment: @Michaellogg, as of 1.3.0.1 that is true, before that version there was a stacking effect.

Comment: Well I feel dumb. I even checked the History section on that page before I said anything, but completely missed it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

For me its actually a bit easy to get a Nazar. I would just go to the Dungeon, Water Candle in Hand+Water Candle Placed+Blattle Potion+Minion: Easy Nazar.
WARNING: This Comment is made from a pre 1.2.5 User. I use 1.2.4.

- My version is 1.2.4, but IDK why the monsters drop their respective banners :I