# How to get the horseman blade drop?

Tags: terraria

Can't get the horseman blade drop, I've killed the pumpking 20 times today. Is there any caveat to make this happen besides invoking the pumpkin moon, fighting the waves and killing the pumpking?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to buffing your luck as much as possible, as mentioned by Skye-AT, you should make sure you're not just killing the wave 7 Pumpking over and over: the drop rate scales with the wave, so while on wave 7 Pumpking will only drop the blade at about a 1% rate, on wave 15 Pumpking will drop it at a 12.5% rate.

If you're playing on Expert mode, the drop rate penalty is removed on wave 10 instead of wave 15.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're just having bad luck (as in your real life luck).

First thing first, their drop rate is very low according to [fandom](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/The_Horseman%27s_Blade), just only 1.04%(PC, Console and modded version of Terraria after ver. 1.4), or 1.79%(Old-gen Console such as PS3, Windows Phone, [old Chinese version](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Old_Chinese_version) and modded version of Terraria before ver. 1.3).

However, if you're playing on PC or current-gen console such as PS4 or mobile version, you can increase the chance of drop by lacking up your Luck (as in in-game stats), to 12.5/14.29%.

For lacking up your Luck, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253060/is-there-any-way-to-increase-the-drop-rate-of-items).